# Can't load styles with longer link with Laravel (blade.php)

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I am building a web page and i have a problem about the page. In the 'routes', I created a custom link:

```
Route::get('/customization/footer', 'Controller@footer');
```

So, the page will be loaded using `https://myweb.com/customization/footer`. But, using that link, the page didn't load the style (css and js). And then, when I changed the link on 'routes' becoming:

```
Route::get('/footer', 'Controller@footer');
```

the page loaded perfectly (no problem found).

The reason I used a longer link is to make it tidier. Does anyone know about how to solve this problem? I need help

> P.S.: The problem is not in how the style files (like css and js files) are called. The problem is in the link I used as I stated in my question

Comment: how do you link your styles. If the link is not relative to the sites base domain, it might not be loading. (as it wants to load /customization/path-to-css-file)

Comment: @GertB. I link the style with this code:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
and i did it to every other file (the other files are run well)

Comment: change it to `href="/css/main.css"`, I would also advise you to use the `asset()` helper. found in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset

Comment: thanks for the advice, but nothing's changed. still got the problem

Comment: check console you found 404 error for style files? if not then i think there are you spilt header, footer, menu in sperate file & then you will included this using @yield( ). please share detail about how to you spilt header, footer, menu files & also share path about header, footer, menu & &  your main content file path also.

Comment: @HarshPatel neither splitting the sections (header, footer, style) nor making it separated solve this problem :( (anyway, I split them using @ yield and i put them on different directory and there is no problem with it)

Comment: @ArnoldSianturi ok, then add your source code in question then we can identify your problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You havent shown how to include styles on your page.
The best way to connect styles is via a helper asset()

```html
<link href = "{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel = "stylesheet">
```

(for path /public/css/app.css)

Comment: The spaces in `asset ('css / app.css')` wont be a problem? Using the asset helper is indeed the best option.

Comment: @GertB. The space doesn't matter.

Comment: This works as expected. Regardless of nesting

Comment: There's no differences, the page still doesn't load it

Comment: I meant the spaces in the path. I would remove them anyway

Comment: @ArnoldSianturi is your css file in `/public/css/app.css` ? `{{asset ('css/app.css') }} ` should load them.

Comment: yes, the files are in public_html, but the styles aren't loaded

Comment: @ArnoldSianturi hold on. your application is inside public_html? thats not right. the laravel public directory needs to be the root dir of your domain.

Comment: @GertB. no of course :D I meant, the 'style' files are in public_html, the other files are save

Comment: @ArnoldSianturi the style file should be in the laravel public dir ... or any subfolder of that dir